# how to display spesific cell data in label.text in gridview in asp.net(c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
    hi every one please help me .I have asp.net c# website I have on my form:
```

1. sqldatasource1
   2.gridview1
   3.textbox1(for input a year) and dropdownlist1(for select a month)
   4.textbox2(for input a year) and dropdownlist2(for select a month)
   5.two label
   6.I want when I select a month and year, the specific data in gridview1 display in label1 and label2 
   7.then I want to calculate that data e.g "+" or "*" or ...

   8. I do this in vb.net my code for get data is

:

```
 Public Sub get_data1()
        cn.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable("shakhes")
        Dim rs As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from shakhes where sal_tadieh = '" & TextBoxX4.Text & "' and mah_tadieh = '" & ComboBoxEx3.Text & "'", cn)
        rs.Fill(dt)
        ShakhesDataGridView.DataSource = dt
        ShakhesDataGridView.Refresh()
        Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count
        rs.Dispose()
        cn.Close()
        If Val(Label1.Text) = 1 Then
            Dim i As Integer
            i = ShakhesDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
            TextBoxX2.Text = ShakhesDataGridView.Item(2, i).Value
        ElseIf Val(Label1.Text) = 0 Then
            TextBoxX2.Text = "there is no data"
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub get_data2()
        cn.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable("shakhes")
        Dim rs As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from shakhes where sal_tadieh = '" & TextBoxX5.Text & "' and mah_tadieh = '" & ComboBoxEx4.Text & "'", cn)
        rs.Fill(dt)
        ShakhesDataGridView.DataSource = dt
        ShakhesDataGridView.Refresh()
        Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count
        rs.Dispose()
        cn.Close()
        If Val(Label1.Text) = 1 Then
            Dim i As Integer
            i = ShakhesDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
            TextBoxX3.Text = ShakhesDataGridView.Item(2, i).Value
             ElseIf Val(Label1.Text) = 0 Then
            TextBoxX3.Text = "there is no data"
        End If
    End Sub


9. my code for calculate data:



 Public Sub boro()
        Dim a As Decimal
        Dim b, c As Decimal
        Dim fo_labl As Decimal
        a = TextBoxX1.Text
        b = Val(TextBoxX2.Text)
        c = Val(TextBoxX3.Text)
        If b = 0 Or c = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("no data", "notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            LabelX5.Text = (c / b) * a
        End If
        fo_labl = Val(LabelX5.Text)
        LabelX5.Text = FormatNumber(fo_labl, NumDigitsAfterDecimal:=0, GroupDigits:=TriState.True)
    End Sub
    Private Sub tadieh_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Ejra_dbDataSet.shakhes' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.ShakhesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Ejra_dbDataSet.shakhes)
        expo()
        display_data()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBoxEx3_SelectedIndexChanged_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxEx3.SelectedIndexChanged
        get_data1()
        LabelX6.Text = TextBoxX2.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBoxEx4_SelectedIndexChanged_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxEx4.SelectedIndexChanged
        get_data2()
        LabelX7.Text = TextBoxX3.Text
    End Sub
    Private Sub ButtonX3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonX3.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxX1_KeyPress1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBoxX1.KeyPress
        e.Handled = Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 48 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 57) Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxX1_TextChanged_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBoxX1.TextChanged
        Try
            TextBoxX1.Text = Format(CULng(TextBoxX1.Text), "#,#")
            TextBoxX1.SelectionStart = TextBoxX1.Text.Length
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShakhesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.ShakhesBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Ejra_dbDataSet)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxX4_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBoxX4.TextChanged
        get_data1()
        LabelX6.Text = TextBoxX2.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxX5_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBoxX5.TextChanged
        get_data2()
        LabelX7.Text = TextBoxX3.Text
    End Sub


    Private Sub ButtonX1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonX1.Click
        If TextBoxX1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("please fill", "notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        ElseIf TextBoxX4.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("please fill", "notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        ElseIf TextBoxX5.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("please fill", "notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        ElseIf ComboBoxEx3.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("please fill", "notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        ElseIf ComboBoxEx4.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("please fill", "notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
       Else
            boro()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

10. now I want do same thing for asp.net but my problem is that gridview dose not have same property e.g

    ```
    i = ShakhesDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index


    TextBoxX2.Text = ShakhesDataGridView.Item(2, i).Value
    ```

11.by the way i know about asp.net and c# a liitle and i am an amateur

Comment: Is this a Homework ? Changing Vb code to C# ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is so I can't answer it but I wanted to note a couple of things about your code as it is now. You are setting yourself up for sql injection by allowing what's entered into a text box to be part of your query. Next you are comparing the value of the text box (a string) to 1 or 0 which it will never be. So there is no way to convert your code to C#, it just needs to be rewritten. To get the row index of your grid you need to loop over the data rows not just check the value of your text box.

Comment: hi thanks for reply really my code in vb.net is :

Comment: hi I edit my code please help me